# Sum involving Binomial numbers and Fibonacci numbers

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to prove the following identity using induction:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}{n\choose j}F_{2n+1-j}=F_{2n+1}-1 $$
I tried expanding the sum using Pascal's identity (or Stifel's relation) and the recurrence formula for Fibonacci numbers.The formula seems to be wrong, so I guess it should be an alternating sum.How can I prove this using the methods above?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you check it for $n=2$?

Comment: Thanks.It doesn´t work lol. I don´t think it works at all. The problem was exactly like this in the book. I guess it should be an alternating sum then.

Comment: I Sorry I get this sum as $S_n=F_{3n+1}-F_{2n+1}$ and give the answer below. Our claim can be check any which way. My result also matches with that of @Robert Israel .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F_k=\frac{a^k-b^k}{\sqrt{5}}, a+b=1, ab=-1,a^2=a+1, b^2=b+1 $. These relations will be used frequently below. Then
$$S_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n} F_{2n+1-j}~ {n \choose j}= \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{a^{2n+1-j}-b^{2n+1-j}}{\sqrt{5}} {n \choose j}.$$
Use binomial summation: $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} {n \choose k} a^{-j}=(1+1/a)^n-1$$
$$\implies S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} [ a^{2n+1} ((1+1/a)^n-1)-b^{2n+1} ((1+1/b)^n-1)]$$
$$\implies S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left [a^{2n+1}(1-b)^n-b^{2n+1}(1-a)^n]-[a^{2n+1}-b^{2n+1}]\right]$$
$$\implies S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[(a)^{3n+1}-(a)^{3n+1} ]-F_{2n+1}= F_{3n+1}-F_{2n+1}~~~(*)$$
We get a different result from that of OP. Our result can be checked numerically by hand or at Mathematica.

Comment: I didn´t understand what happened from the first line to the second.

Comment: @Lucas Ferreria I have now added a line there.

Answer (score 1):

The right side is $F_{3n+1} - F_{2n+1}$, not
$F_{2n+1}-1$.  Try using Binet's formula.

Comment: If it is an alternating sum, the RHS is correct

Comment: You mean, $\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1} {n \choose j} F_{2n+1-j} = F_{2n+1} - 1$.

Comment: Yes, i guess so